# using beautifulsoup decompose() to get rid of multiple unwanted tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to clean up HTML so that all I have is the relevant text I want. The following code cleans up the superscript tags with the first defined function, I wan't to do the same thing but with the 'h4', 'h1', 'a', and 'li' tags before I use .get_text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+14%3A12-14&version=NIV"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

def supClean(verseWithSup):
    for sup in verseWithSup:
        verseWithSup.sup.decompose()
    return verseWithSup

def verseExtract(soup):
    verseName = soup.find(class_="passage-display-bcv").get_text()
    verseWithSup = soup.find(class_="passage-text")
    verseBody = supClean(verseWithSup).get_text()
    return verseName, verseBody

verseName, verseBody = (verseExtract(soup))

print(verseName)
print(verseBody)
```

I get this right now:

> Luke 14:12-14New International Version (NIV) Then Jesus said to his
>   host, “When you give a luncheon or dinner, do not invite your friends,
>   your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or your rich neighbors; if
>   you do, they may invite you back and so you will be repaid. But when
>   you give a banquet, invite the poor, the crippled, the lame, the
>   blind, 14 and you will be blessed. Although they cannot repay you, you
>   will be repaid at the resurrection of the righteous.”  Cross
>   references:Luke 14:13 : ver 21 Luke 14:14 : Ac 24:15
>
> New International Version (NIV) Holy Bible, New International
>   Version®, NIV® Copyright ©1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by Biblica, Inc.®
>   Used by permission. All rights reserved worldwide.

But all I wan't is this:

> Then Jesus said to his host, “When you give a luncheon or dinner, do
>   not invite your friends, your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or
>   your rich neighbors; if you do, they may invite you back and so you
>   will be repaid. But when you give a banquet, invite the poor, the
>   crippled, the lame, the blind, 14 and you will be blessed. Although
>   they cannot repay you, you will be repaid at the resurrection of the
>   righteous.”

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="passage-text">
 <div class="passage-wrap">
  <div class="passage-content passage-class-0">
   <div class="version-NIV result-text-style-normal text-html ">
    <h1 class="passage-display">
     <span class="passage-display-bcv">
      Luke 14:12-14
     </span>
     <span class="passage-display-version">
      New International Version (NIV)
     </span>
    </h1>
    <p>
     <span class="text Luke-14-12" id="en-NIV-25566">
      Then Jesus said to his host,
      <span class="woj">
       “When you give a luncheon or dinner, do not invite your friends, your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or your rich neighbors; if you do, they may invite you back and so you will be repaid.
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="text Luke-14-13" id="en-NIV-25567">
      <span class="woj">
       But when you give a banquet, invite the poor, the crippled, the lame, the blind,
       <sup class="crossreference" data-cr="#cen-NIV-25567A" data-link='(&lt;a href="#cen-NIV-25567A" title="See cross-reference A"&gt;A&lt;/a&gt;)'>
       </sup>
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="text Luke-14-14" id="en-NIV-25568">
      <span class="woj">
       <sup class="versenum">
        14
       </sup>
       and you will be blessed. Although they cannot repay you, you will be repaid at the resurrection of the righteous.”
       <sup class="crossreference" data-cr="#cen-NIV-25568B" data-link='(&lt;a href="#cen-NIV-25568B" title="See cross-reference B"&gt;B&lt;/a&gt;)'>
       </sup>
      </span>
     </span>
    </p>
    <div class="crossrefs hidden">
     <h4>
      Cross references:
     </h4>
     <ol>
      <li id="cen-NIV-25567A">
       <a href="#en-NIV-25567" title="Go to Luke 14:13">
        Luke 14:13
       </a>
       :
       <a class="crossref-link" data-bibleref="Luke 14:21" href="/passage/?search=Luke+14%3A21&amp;version=NIV">
        ver 21
       </a>
      </li>
      <li id="cen-NIV-25568B">
       <a href="#en-NIV-25568" title="Go to Luke 14:14">
        Luke 14:14
       </a>
       :
       <a class="crossref-link" data-bibleref="Acts 24:15" href="/passage/?search=Acts+24%3A15&amp;version=NIV">
        Ac 24:15
       </a>
      </li>
     </ol>
    </div>
    <!--end of crossrefs-->
   </div>
   <div class="publisher-info-bottom with-single">
    <strong>
     <a href="/versions/New-International-Version-NIV-Bible/">
      New International Version
     </a>
     (NIV)
    </strong>
    <p>
     Holy Bible, New International Version®, NIV® Copyright ©1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by
     <a href="http://www.biblica.com/">
      Biblica, Inc.®
     </a>
     Used by permission. All rights reserved worldwide.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't get you wat do you want us to do? be clear

Comment: I edited it for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. If you wanna shake off `12`, `13` and `14` from the verse as well then let me know.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests           

link= "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+14%3A12-14&version=NIV"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("[id^='en-NIV-']"):
    print(item.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
12 Then Jesus said to his host, “When you give a luncheon or dinner, do not invite your friends, your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or your rich neighbors; if you do, they may invite you back and so you will be repaid.
13 But when you give a banquet, invite the poor, the crippled, the lame, the blind,
14 and you will be blessed. Although they cannot repay you, you will be repaid at the resurrection of the righteous.”
```

Or to get rid off the verse number you can try like below:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring           

link= "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+14%3A12-14&version=NIV"  
root = fromstring(requests.get(link).text)
for item in root.cssselect("[id^='en-NIV-'],.woj"):
    for data in item:data.drop_tree()
    print(item.text_content())
```

Result:

```
Then Jesus said to his host, 
“When you give a luncheon or dinner, do not invite your friends, your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or your rich neighbors; if you do, they may invite you back and so you will be repaid.
But when you give a banquet, invite the poor, the crippled, the lame, the blind,
and you will be blessed. Although they cannot repay you, you will be repaid at the resurrection of the righteous.”
```

Comment: Getting rid of the verse # is something I need. You are also using lxml instead of the built in python HTML processor, is that a better option for this?

Comment: If you have `lxml` library installed then the solution i wanna give to remove the verse number might be in use. Thanks.

Comment: Go through this BeautifulSoup documentation link [Link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) where clearly stated that `lxml’s HTML parser Very fast BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")`.

Comment: I have lxml installed and functioning. I used a different method than what you gave me to get the text how I want but I'm curious to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer provided worked, I eventually arrived at this code to do what I wanted in bs4.

```
for item in soup.select("sup, div.publisher-info-bottom.with-single"):
    item.decompose()
```

I then used the below to get the text and format it the way I wanted it.

```
verseBody = soup.select("div.passage-text p")
formedVerse = ""
for p in verseBody:
    formedVerse += p.get_text() + "\n\n"
```